# Coroutine couldn't be started because the game object 'Scene Loader' is inactive

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine, scene-manager

I have already searched in the Internet, also this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135385/coroutine-not-starting-due-to-inactive-game-object), and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999487/start-coroutine-on-an-inactive-de-activated-gameobject) but didn't find the specific problem I have now.

I have a main scene with 2 buttons, where each button should open other scene (button 1 => scene 1, button 2 = > scene 2) and in each of these scenes I have a back button that should go back to the main scene.

I manage to do that successfully but when I use a `Coroutine` so I can have a delay of 2 seconds while loading the next scene, I get the following error when I click "Back to main scene" button:

```
Coroutine couldn't be started because the the game object 'Scene Loader' is inactive!
```

Here is my code:

```
public class SceneLoader : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool check = true;

    public void LoadNextScene(int numberOfScene)
    {  
        StartCoroutine(LoadAfterSeconds(numberOfScene));    
    }

    private IEnumerator LoadAfterSeconds(int numberOfScene)
    {
        while (check)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);

            SceneManager.LoadScene(numberOfScene);
        }

    }

}
```

When I am in the main screen and I click on the button 1 or 2 to go to the other scenes it's working as intended after 2 seconds, but when I click "Back to main scene" it doesn't do anything and I get the error that the game object 'Scene Loader' is inactive!

I know I could use Invoke() but I would like to understand what I am doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: No need for the `while(check)`. If you use the method `LoadNextScene(int numberOfScene)`, the program will constantly reload the scene that you load first. The line `yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);` alone will take care of the delay.  
You need to make sure the GameObject that has your `SceneLoader` component attached is active in the inspector.

Comment: Thank you @ZzAtomiic for your answer. I tried it with and without the `while(check)` but no difference.

Comment: I have already checked this post (also mentioned it in the description) but didn't help me.

Comment: Are you sure that the GameObject that has the `SceneLoader` component attached is active? Can you post a screenshot of its inspector?

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear. You are getting the error on click of the "Back to main scene button", please post the screenshot of the scene hierarchy and inspector of the back button of the Scene1/Scene2.

Comment: If someone have the same problem and still reading this, I found what was the problem.
I assigned the prefab(asset) in onClick event and not the active instance of it that I had in the scene.